# Send command Line to Android using Java

Tags: java, android, shell, command-line

I got a server applicatino in java in my computer and multiples virtual machines with Android OS. I would like execute the following command line in VM:

```
su am start -n  <PackageName>/ <OtherAtribute>
```

Look what I already have:

The call:

```
cvb.accessShell(ip, 5555);
cvb.startApp(appPackageName, mainPath);
```

THe functions accessShell and startApp:

```
cvb.accessShell(ip, 5555);
cvb.startApp(appPackageName, mainPath);


public void accessShell(String ip, int port) {
      String script = "/home/decom/1018119/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s "
            + ip + ":" + port + " shell";
      System.out.println(script);
      try {
         System.out.println("Get in");
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script); // stuck here
         System.out.println("Get out");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Cant connect to shell");
      }
   }

public void startApp(String appPackageName, String mainPath) {
      String script = "su am start -n " + appPackageName + "/" + mainPath;
      System.out.println(script);
      try {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Cant connect to shell");
      }
   }
```

The problem is (like the comments on code): My code stuck at shell access and when I run the exactly command by terminal, it works ok.

I tried read the output and nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -la");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

so, in your code:

```
try {
     System.out.println("Get in");
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script); 
     System.out.println("Get out");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
  } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("Cant connect to shell");
  }
```

Comment: Some explanation should be welcomed for the questionner.